# Display application name dynamically from configuration in Play framework 2

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am working on a Play 2 framework (v 2.3.7) - Java template, and I am trying to display the name of the application dynamically from the configuration files.

Would anyone please advise about the solution or the approach for doing this?
The application name can be found in build.sbt file. Can I get it from there? Or shall I define it in application.conf?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

build.sbt is not accessible at runtime.

You can add `application.name=FOO` to application.conf and then access it with `play.Play.application().configuration().getString("application.name")`.

Comment: Thank you very much @cosmolev for your quick reply! I am able to display the application name dynamically now!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sbt-buildinfo](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo) plugin for sbt to expose sbt settings to your application.

Sbt buildinfo is a plugin for sbt which plugs-in a code generator and generates the code source for a scala object which can be referenced from your app.

The plugin defines a few settings to be exposed (name, version,...) and lets you configure more.

This also works outside play and doesn't require you to duplicate settings value manually.